# Rhino-Licensing for .NET is throwing an LicenseExpiredException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, rhino-licensing

I'm using `Windows 8.1` with latest .NET core, and `Visual Studio 2015`. I followed the [following article](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/) from James Gregory to create a Winform app. But when I assert the license, it gives me the following error: `Rhino.Licensing.LicenseExpiredException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Expiration Date : 6/16/2016 12:00:00 AM
  Source=Rhino.Licensing
  StackTrace:
       at Rhino.Licensing.AbstractLicenseValidator.HasExistingLicense()
       at Rhino.Licensing.AbstractLicenseValidator.AssertValidLicense()
       at Rhino.Licensing.LicenseValidator.AssertValidLicense()
       at Winfrm_RhinoTest.Form1.ApplyLicense()....`

The code ran on June 15, 2016 and the expiration date was set to June 16, 2016.

The C# code to generate the license is as follows:

```
string publicKey = File.ReadAllText("publicKey.xml");
            new LicenseValidator(publicKey, @"C:\Users\Public\license.xml").AssertValidLicense();
```

The license.xml file was generated and used in the code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<license id="b45c43a5-a639-4fa4-8bf7-38531b19072e" expiration="2016-06-16T00:00:00.0000000" type="Trial">
  <name>Bilbo</name>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>d+eI2/Bdp/VYJ8pi/ufmJGeRW6k=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>Zd2oTinP0zE4/4haA5e4810MdG3upx1LlzkXALsTJYDgXLacDoc96diObTkxDipUBMUeFuf3ARBPtFRHGIqHjEfhn/FqZD+CrcsvjhbMSIROpaqqcOpzFwOamjQ+jPLW+BOf5qvMA0n4LNCm8B5qnifc/08zTXTSUpAqLiCY8zk=</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</license>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [source code for rhino-licensing](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing/blob/1fc90c984b0c3012465a73afae0a53492c969eb5/Rhino.Licensing/AbstractLicenseValidator.cs), the date comparison is done in UTC

```
result = DateTime.UtcNow < ExpirationDate;
```

Which will throw the exception with Expiration Date as parameter

```
throw new LicenseExpiredException("Expiration Date : " + ExpirationDate)
```

Since the exception you shown indicate the ExpirationDate is the start of 16 June, the most likely reason is you're running the code in 15 June in your timezone, that is actually already 16 June in UTC, which is 19 hours already at the time of this post.

Comment: Thank you for `well explained` cause of the error and helping the readers (including myself) of this post. I had performed the testing around 11:30 PM US Eastern time on June 15, 2016 that is 4 hours behind UTC time zone. I tested the same code on June 16 around 10:30 AM US Easter time and set the expiration date to be June 17 and it did not throw an error since June 17, 12AM UTC was still ahead enough of 10:30 AM US Easter time.